# how to unpack a struct with uint16_t type in python

Tags: python, c, struct, binary, elf

I'm trying to unpack ElfHeader in python. Type of `e_type` in Elf64_Edhr struct is uint16_t, How can I unpack it? I only found a way to unpack 4 bit unsigned int in python struct docs.

Comment: Look at the `struct` module documentation again. The format code for unsigned short is `H`.

Comment: Thanks, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably every machine Python supports has 8 bits per byte, so a 16-bit integer uses 2 bytes. We want the size to be the same on every machine, so we look at the *standard size* column. The format for an unsigned integer with a standard size of 2 bytes or 16 bits is `H`.

For the standard size to be relevant, the `unpack` pattern must start with `<`, `>`, `!` or `=` depending on endianness. ELF supports both little- and big-endian values depending on the byte at offset 0x05 of the file, so your pattern would start with either `<` or `>` depending on what the endianness of the file.

- If the byte at offset 0x05 is `1`, it's a little-endian file, so your pattern must start with `<`.

  LE uint16_t 0x3456 = 13398 is `b'\x56\x34'`

  ```
  >>> x = b'\x56\x34'
  >>> struct.unpack('<H', x)
  (13398,)
  ```
- If the byte at offset 0x05 is `2`, it's a big-endian file, so your pattern must start with `>`.

  BE uint16_t 0x3456 = 13398 is `b'\x34\x56'`

  ```
  >>> x = b'\x34\x56'
  >>> struct.unpack('>H', x)
  (13398,)
  ```